# Unity in android: failed to read firebase options from the app's resources

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Firebase package in Unity. It works perfectly fine when I run the game in the Unity editor, however, when I build the game for Android, I get this error:

> Failed to read firebase options from the app's resources either make
>   sure google-services.json is included in your build or specify options
>   directly

I already have google-services.json file in the Assets folder and I added the following block of code as suggested here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup):

```
private void ConfirmGooglePlayerServicesRequirements()
    {
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
                // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
                app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

                // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
                firebaseIsReadyToBeUsed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
                // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try forcing the Play Services Resolver to run. See this: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef

It may also help to follow this video: https://youtu.be/A6du3DUTIPI

If you're still having issues, try to enable verbose logging for the play services resolver and post any messages that may occur. Also try to avoid any special folder names and post an update if that fixes it: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html (obviously it has to be in Assets, but avoid "Editor" for instance).

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me, 2020 version, see here:

> In order to support versions of Unity that do not have the ability to customize the Gradle build, the Firebase editor tool generates Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values/google-services.xml as an Android resource to be packaged into an Android build, so that the Firebase SDK can use it to initialize the default FirebaseApp instance.

> In Unity 2020, all Android resources must be in directories with a .androidlib suffix. If your project is using a Firebase SDK that generates an Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase directory, **rename** it to Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase.androidlib. **Make sure it contains AndroidManifest.xml, project.properties and res/values/google-services.xml.**

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#missing_firebase_android_config_file_in_unity_2020

Comment: This worked for me using Unity 2020.2.2f1.

Answer (score 1):

In your mainTemplate file you need to add this at the bottom:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
            res.srcDirs += (unityProjectPath + '/Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values/google-services.xml')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with Unity 2020.1.17f1

Answer (score 1):

I faced the Same Problem with Unity 2022.
OS : Windows , Target : Android

Firebase.Editor.dll was not working because it did not find Xcode Plugin.
Solution : Install iOS Build Support on Windows as well. And It magically solved all the errors related to all google products (Admob , Analytics, Crashlytics )
Strange but Worked !